# R: ggplot fill one factor in a 2x2 factorial experiment

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

I ran a 2x2 factorial experiment on several different plant species. I am having a heck of a time properly plotting all this.

Dummy data:

```
Data <- data.frame(
species = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4),
F1 = rep(letters[25:26], times = 8), 
F2 = rep(letters[11:12], each = 2, times = 4),
mean = runif(16, min=0, max=1),
se = (runif(16, min=0, max=1))/10)
```

I want the species name on the X axis, and 4 separate points(+ SE bars), 2 for each factor. One factor will be filled or empty, the other will be  Here is what I've got so far:

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)
ggplot(Data, aes(species, mean, fill = factor(F1), shape = factor(F2))) +
geom_point(size = 3, position = pd) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), position = pd)
```

However this is not actually making factor 1 a filled or unfilled shape. I've followed along with several examples in mtcars which I've gotten working fine. What is going wrong here?

For what it's worth, color works fine, but I need it to be filled or empty, so seems like I might be using fill wrong?

Comment: Just change `fill` to `colour` and you are set. That will also color the error bars. If you really want filled plotting symbols you can use `+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24))`.

Comment: This is a good resource for symbol shapes and line types in ggplot2 and base R graphics: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fill` aesthetic is used to fill bars with colors.  Points, are "solid" or not.

I don't know of one step solution to build the plot with a points being solid or not by a factor.  However, there building such a plot is not too difficult.

Let's start with building `Data`

```
library(ggplot2)

Data <- data.frame(species = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4),
                   F1      = rep(letters[25:26], times = 8), 
                   F2      = rep(letters[11:12], each = 2, times = 4),
                   mean    = runif(16, min=0, max=1),
                   se      = (runif(16, min=0, max=1))/10)
```

Add a column to `Data` combining `F1` and `F2`.  You could use the `interaction()` function, but I'll use `paste` (`paste0(...)` is equivalent to `paste(..., sep = "")`) to build the column and set it as a `factor`.

```
Data$F1F2 <- factor(with(Data, paste0("F1 = ", F1, "; F2 = ", F2)))
levels(Data$F1F2)
```

Now, in the `ggplot` object use `scale_shape_manual` to map specific point characters to the levels of `Data$F1F2`.  In this example, point characters `c(1, 2, 16, 17)` correspond to a non-solid circle, non-solid triangle, solid circle, and a solid triangle.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.5)
ggplot(Data) +
  aes(species, mean, color = species, shape = F1F2) +
  geom_point(size = 3, position = pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), position = pd) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Factors",
                     values = c(1, 2, 16, 17))
```

The resulting graphic is below.  I added a color aesthetic to help me see the grouping by `species`.

[image]